# D3.js output store in database

Tags: javascript, d3.js

this is "http://jsbin.com/acatof/3/edit?html,output" link of pie chart. Now if go for view source, then you can see that pie chart is made by new calculated code.

My problem is that I want to save that code in my database but i cant. I tried to search on internet but didnt get the answer.

If you can suggest me some things that would be very helpful.

Comment: just store the values which you called "dataset" ?

Comment: I think he mean to save the whole code generated in html.

Comment: I believe this is the 3rd time you've asked this same question, and it's not becoming clearer each time. Can you explain more about your goals for doing this and perhaps we can suggest an alternate approach.

Comment: `innerHTML` doesn't do what you want to do?

Comment: @supernova : I can store dataset value but I am not able to use that data with pie chart in  another page.

Comment: @fsi : yes, I want to store the whole code generated in html.

Comment: @explunit : Sir, after putting the value in dataset and after the whole code got run then a new code generated in the background of the html.
That is the real code which shows the real visualization.
So i want to store that new generated code in my database.

Plz help me and if still you do not understand then plz tell me I will try again to make you clear.....

Comment: Inner html means? @Oleg

Comment: @rohitnarang `svg.node().innerHTML`

Comment: @Oleg: thanks for your reply. Can you explain me a little bit more.

This is the basic example "http://jsbin.com/acatof/3/edit?html,output".

Comment: What do you want to know? That expression returns the generated code (at least it does in Chrome, not sure about other browsers).

Comment: @Oleg:  thanx, I did not try it yet but after try i will tell you.

Comment: If you can't use the pie chart in another page what about just saving the svg - just google d3js export svg and you should get some hints

Comment: @supernova: Its also good but not what I want. My pie chart may have some special effects then its not going to work anymore. But thanks for your reply..

Comment: @Oleg  thanks, your suggestion works.  thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of this question is-

svg.node().innerHTML or svg.node().outerHTML .